# Trazer dados de nós diferentes firebase - javascript

Tags: javascript, react, firebase

Olá! Tenho uma tabela que é alimentada por um Realtime Database - Firebase. A questão é: Meu banco tem 2 nós mas só consigo trazer os dados se especificar de qual eu quero. Como faço para ler os dados de todos os nós?
[abaixo dos UniqueId's eu consigo pegar tudo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbynD.jpg)

```
export default function Tabela() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //const query = ref(db, "Incendios/"); -> Quero trazer tudo que está abaixo deste!
    const query = ref(db, "Incendios/sT5YYZKbkkWy9QG4NnUfYWFmVgQ2"); -> se eu fizer assim, funciona.
    //const query = ref(db, "Incendios/hbx6kMcZmaaMWFP8R0SvcWmYuWK2"); -> assim também
    
    return onValue(query, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      for (const [key] of Object.entries(data)) {
        console.log(key);
      }
      console.log("dados", data);
      setProjects([])
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        Object.values(data).forEach((project) => {
          setProjects((projects) => [...projects, project]);
        
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Usuário</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Status</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Email</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Latitude</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Longitude</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">Imagem</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {projects.map((row,index) => (
            <StyledTableRow key={index}>
              <StyledTableCell align="right"> {row.usuario.nome}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.status}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.usuario.email}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.localizacao.latitude}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.localizacao.longitude}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right"><img src={row.imagem} alt="sem imagem" id="imagem-miniatura" width={100} height={100}></img></StyledTableCell>
            </StyledTableRow>
          ))}
```

Eu estou "aprendendo" Javascript agora meio que na marra, por isso tanta dificuldade.